# Java Method signature with generic return class

Tags: java, methods, generics, declaration, signature

What is the difference between the following 2 method signature:

```
public <T extends MyClass> Set<T> getMyList() {...}

public Set<? extends MyClass> getMyList() {...}
```

Comment: Odd that you should be return returning a "list" as a `Set`. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first one you can use it as:

```
Set<MyClass> set = thing.getMyList();
Set<MyDerivedClass> set = thing.getMyList();
Set<?> set = thing.getMyList();
Set<? extends MyClass> set = thing.getMyList();
Set<? extends MyDerivedClass> set = thing.getMyList();
```

For the second, you are more limited:

```
Set<?> set = thing.getMyList();
Set<? extends MyClass> set = thing.getMyList();
```

How would you expect to implement the first? The second is bad because it forces client code to use wildcards.

Answer (score 3):

In the first one, `T` is accessible in method body, while in the second one it is not. Whether that's useful depends on the method's job.